# Ubuntu 16 LTS on Asus K8V SE Deluxe

Tags: asus, raid

Just to save everyone some time, use the IDE controllers not the SATA RAID controllers for the boot drives. No matter what I tried Ubuntu would always error on the GRUB boot at the end. All other files would load, but always got the error.

Dug up some old IDE drives, connected them to the board and Ubuntu installed without a problem. I'll try connecting the SATA drives later for additional storage.

I believe the issue is with the fake RAID used by the ASUS board. Neither the Promise or VIA controllers were able to successfully work. I also could not find a SATA port that wasn't a RAID connect, so I just went IDE.

BTW, anyone know if there are any UpNp servers for Ubuntu? MediaTomb doesn't appear as a 16 LTS compatible app.